# Whole number distribution for a sum such that no two whole numbers are same.

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math, combinations

> In how many ways can $18$ identical balls be distributed among three
> girls such that each one of them gets at least one ball and no two
> girls get the same number of balls?

Each girl will get one ball so let us distribute one ball to each girl and now we are left with 15 balls. Let three girls be denoted by $G_1$, $G_2$ and $G_3$. Now it has become a situation where we have to find

> $G_1+G_2+G_3 = 15$

It has now become a case of finding whole number distribution where $G_1$, $G_2$ and $G_3$ need to be different whole numbers. Now as the sum is small here so we can form cases where at least $2$ girls will get the same number of balls such as 
$5+5+5=0+0+15 = 1+1+13 = 2 +2 +11= 3+3 +6 = 4+4+7 = 15$

But what if the sum would have been large. Is there a formula to find the number of ways of whole number distribution for a particular sum where the whole numbers are different?

Comment: Might be easier to count the cases in which two (or more) get the same number, then subtract from the total.

Comment: @lulu : There is no specific formula. What if the sum would have been a large value?  Also, I tried doing that way by making cases, as I have mentioned in the description but my answer is coming $120$.

Comment: Not sure what you are looking for.  The problem you stated is easy, for the reason I gave.  Yes, more complicated problems would be, well, more complicated.

Comment: Should say:  your calculation appears to be incomplete.  first use [Stars and Bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) to get the total (ignoring the requirement that the numbers be distinct).  Now, note that a case like $\{1,1,13\}$ is actually $3$ cases since you can give the $13$ to any of the three girls.

Comment: For whatever it's worth, I wouldn't think the number of balls would be the problem.  Rather, the number of girls.  If you had a lot of places to distribute the balls, then the "all distinct" requirement becomes very subtle and hard to work with.  So long as you stick with $3$ girls, the problem ought to be easy no matter how many balls you are distributing.

Comment: @lulu Interesting point.  Initially, I assumed that my approach was inferior in all cases.  Suppose that you had $5$ girls and $1000$ balls.  $5G_1 + 4x_1 + 3x_2 + 2x_3 + x_4 = 1000$ is no walk in the park.  On the other hand, with Inclusion-Exclsusion, there are $\binom{5}{2}$ choices for which $2$ girls have the same amount.  Also, you could have (for example) $3$ girls all having one amount and the other $2$ girls both having the same amount that is different from the first  amount.  So, this approach is also ugly.

Comment: @user2661923  These things always come down to cases.  With a small number of girls, it's easy to describe the cases.  With a large number...well all sorts of patterns are possible..  In theory, the same sort of analysis ought to go throw, but practically speaking it gets unwieldy very fast.

Answer (score 2):

Say $g_1$ and $g_2$ are number of balls distributed to girl $G_1$ and $G_2$ respectively then all we want is number of solutions to $~x_1 + x_2 = 15$ where $x_1, x_2$ are non-negative, $x_1$ is an even number and $g_1 = g_2 = x_1/2$. Between $0 - 15$, there are $16/2 = 8~$ even numbers. This includes arrangement where all three girls have same number of balls.

Also, we have $3$ ways to choose two girls to have equal number of balls.

We know that total number of arrangements are,

$ \displaystyle {15 + 3 - 1 \choose 3 - 1}$

So the answer would be,

$ \displaystyle {15 + 3 - 1 \choose 3 - 1} - 3 \cdot 8 + 2~$. We add $2$ in the end as we over-subtracted arrangements where all three girls had same number of balls.

Comment: I got the same answer through a different route.  +1: In retrospect, your approach is better, since it allows the use of Stars and Bars analysis, and therefore generalizes much better than mine.

Comment: @user2661923 thanks. Yes it does generalize for $3$ girls but as lulu mentions in one of his comments, the problem is hard to generalize if there are more girls.

Comment: See the comment that I left, following lulu's comment.

Answer (score 0):

In retrospect, the following approach is inferior to the approach taken by Math Lover.  His approach permits the use of Stars and Bars Analysis, with only a mild sprinkling of Inclusion-Exclusion.  So, his approach generalizes much better than my approach.

---

In effect, you have $(3!)$ times the number of solutions where

$$G_1 < G_2 < G_3. \tag1 $$

I could be mistaken, however I think that the constraint in (1) above prevents the problem from being solved by traditional Stars and Bars Analysis.

My approach is as follows:

- As you indicated, the problem bijects to the number of non-negative integer solutions to $G_1 + G_2 + G_3 = 15$, subject to the constraint in (1) above.  Once this is calculated, you then multiply the result by $(3!)$.
- Let $x_1 = G_2 - G_1, x_2 = G_3 - G_2.$

Then $G_1 + G_2 + G_3 = 3G_1 + 2x_1 + x_2 = 15.$

Here, you have the added constraints that $x_1$ and $x_2$ are positive integers.

These constraints are so *off-beat* and the numbers are so small, and the number of variables are so small that the simplest approach is to let $G_1$ go from $0$ through $(4)$ and compute $F(G_1)$ to be the number of satisfying solutions for a specific value of $G_1$.

Then, you take the overall summation and multiply it by $(3!)$.

For a specific value of $G_1$, the problem reduces to determining the number of positive integer solutions to

$$2x_1 + x_2 = 15 - 3G_1.$$

When $G_1$ is even, $x_1$ can range from $1$ through $~\displaystyle \frac{14 - 3G_1}{2}.$

When $G_1$ is odd, $x_1$ can range from $1$ through
$~\displaystyle \frac{13 - 3G_1}{2}.$

So, the final computation is

$$=~ (3!) \times \left[7 + 5 + 4 + 2 + 1\right] = 114.$$